# TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' or 'get' of undefined, Discord.js 12.4.1

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

When I run node, this error pops up: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

the error is here:

```
const cmd = client.command.find(command);
if (!cmd) return;
```

and here's the whole thing:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const cmd = client.command.find(command);
    if (!cmd) return;

    cmd.run(client, message, args);
});
```

Anyone knows what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: The `Client` class has no `command` property : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client. Why are you using `client.command`, did you see this in a tutorial ?

Comment: You might have misspelled `client.commands`

Comment: @Lioness100 AFAIK, there are no `commands` property in the `Client` class either. Are you refering this tutorial : https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/ ? If so, the `client.commands` property is set at runtime, and is not part of the API.

Comment: @Seblor Yeah, I'm referring to the tutorial. It's a very common property to set on your `client` object.